# How to Insert Schedule based Query in Database using Java Application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, scheduled-tasks

Actually In my sample Application using Flex+Java(spring+Hibernate)... In that i'm inserting data into Database.

Hear we are inserting normal values easily i.e only one row operation in Database..

In my example have `Start Date & End Date` and combo box it contain `Monthly Weekly Daily`
Then the problem begins hear...

Ex we Select `StartDate(2012-12-01) & EndDate(2012-12-31)` and combobox value is `Daily` and also time  05:00 PM .....so the meaning of this statement is `Every Day 05:30 PM between 2012-12-01  to 2012-12-31 the Task will execute`

For this Purpose i'm using `QuartTriggerBean` in Spring Frame work so it is working fine but my database inserting only one insert Query...But i want 31 insert Queries...

If we select combo box `Weekly` then 7 insert Queries..and Monthly then 1 insert Query execute...

In this Purpose is their any Class in Java?
Please Help me ....Thankyou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` instead of using quartz. you can have example on [link](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/quartz.html)

Comment: Thankyou for your Quick replay!!! Is their any other way in Spring Framework to Solve this one?

Comment: Spring has scheduling option which internally depedent on quartz http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `java.util.Timer` but instead use the newer `ScheduledExecutorService`.

The idea is simple:

1. Poll the database for jobs by using the ScheduledExecutorService to execute a `HQL SELECT` on all the jobs that have to execute in say the next 5 minutes.
2. Add the jobs to the ScheduledExecutorService scheduling them so that they happen at there desired time ie expectedTime in millis - currentTime in millis is the duration you want to wait.
3. Repeat.

Comment: I updated the doc to clarify it. I'm not going to give you an example till you go look at the Javadoc `ScheduledExecutorService` first and try it. There are plenty of googable resources on the executor service.